# Problema com conversão de string para decimal c#

Tags: c#

Olá, estou tendo um problema com conversão de string para decimal, conforme demonstra o seguinte código:

```
string valor = "0,01";
CultureInfo _provider = new CultureInfo("pt-BR");
decimal valorTratado = Convert.ToDecimal(valor, _provider);
```

A variável valor Tratado deveria estar com o valor 0.01 porém ela está com o valor 1, alguém sabe porque isso acontece?

Comment: Pra mim está ok: https://dotnetfiddle.net/n68roP

Comment: sempre funcionou para mim, porém de um tempo começou a acontecer isso, será alguma configuração do visual studio? ou outro tipo de configuração? quando eu implanto em produção fica ok, porém local acontece isso.

Comment: Substitua o ponto pela vírgula antes de passar para o `ToDecimal`.

Comment: Eu gostaria apenas descobrir o motivo pelo qual esse código sempre funcionou e hoje não funciona mais localmente, estou com o visual studio 2017  15.3.3

Comment: @AlexssandroRochaAquino Provavelmente alguém mexeu nas configurações de localização do computador e trocou o separador de vírgula para ponto (ou qualquer outro).

Comment: As configurações de localização estavam realmente erradas, estava no idioma português brasileiro porém as configurações de número como inglês americano. ao redefinir as configurações para português voltou ao normal.

Answer (score -1):

Alexssandro,

Seu codigo deveria funcionar sem problema, testei o mesmo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Este problema pode ser com a configuração de localização do seu computador. Seu código está certo.